# opencv train classifier never contiueus 3 stage

Tags: python, c++, opencv, machine-learning, viola-jones

I am trying to learn the cascade classifier to learn license plates. I'm running OpenCV 2.4.9 on a Windows 7 server with 16 GB RAM and i7 processor of 3,4 GHz. I want to train the classifier, but it never continuous stage 3.

This is how I made my .vec file on the xxxx there is personal information:

```
D:\xxxx\trainingBinairImages\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_createsamples.exe -info D:\xxxx\trainingBinairImages\positiveNew.dat -bg D:\xxxx\trainingBinairImages\NegativeNew.bg -vec D:\xxxx\trainingBinairImages\output_vec.vec -maxxangle 0 -maxyangle 0 -maxzangle 0 -w 140 -h 40 -num 3311

pause
```

Parameters:

```
D:\xxxx\trainingBinairImages\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data D:\xxxx\trainingBinairImages\result -vec output_vec.vec -bg negativeNew.bg -numPos 2980 -numNeg 3311 -miniHitRate 0.995 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -w 140 -h 40 -featureType HAAR -precalcValBufSize 2048 -precalcIdxBufSize 2048
pause
```

From cmd:

```
 ===== TRAINING 3-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   2980 : 2981
Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated.
```

If needed to get a look in the files I will edit the extra's. I tried to change the positive and negative values the numStages. Change the directory paths etc. Online there are question about this, that I tried without a solved solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is solved on another form [the_link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/56716/opencv-train-classifier-never-contiueus-3-stage/)

> Hmm that is your problem. You need to supply larger images as
>   negative instead of cropped windows. Imagine that you will need a lot
>   of windows! Each negative window that is classified correctly by the
>   previous stages cannot be used again for the new stage. So most people
>   just supply tons of not object images, the software will do its own
>   job of cutting out the negatives randomly for you.